# DataTables filtro por fechas no funciona corractamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, datatables, date

Estoy usando el filtro por fechas de DataTables como esta en su [pagina](https://datatables.net/extensions/datetime/examples/integration/datatables.html)

El problema es que la primera vez que selecciono la fecha no funciona correctamente, al volver a seleccionar ya funciona.

Al seleccionar 28 de noviembre de 2008 no muestra el dato en la tabla y al volver a seleccionar la misma fecha aparece.

[image: Al seleccionar 28 de noviembre de 2008 no muestra el dato en la tabla y al volver a seleccionar aparece]

intente agregando una función cuando se da click en la fecha min, pero sigue sin funcionar

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#min" ).click(function( event ) {

  if($('#min').is(':empty')){
    
    $('#min').val('July 30th 2022');
  }
});});</script
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví con ayuda de esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420839/datatables-date-range-filter) y este [código](https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/2bkbx2y3/9/)

Primero cambie el formato de la fecha en la columna de mi tabla

```
<td>{{ date('d/m/Y', strtotime($dato->fecha)) }}</td>
```

Después importe datapicker

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

y finalmente cambie la función

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
            var min = $('#min').datepicker("getDate");
            var max = $('#max').datepicker("getDate");
            
            var d = data[4].split("/");
            var startDate = new Date(d[1]+ "/" +  d[0] +"/" + d[2]);

            if (min == null && max == null) { return true; }
            if (min == null && startDate <= max) { return true;}
            if(max == null && startDate >= min) {return true;}
            if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) { return true; }
            return false;
        }
    );


    $("#min").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true , dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy"});
    $("#max").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy" });
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    
    $('#min, #max').change(function () {
        table.draw();
    });
});
```