# ¿Como podria reemplazar datepicker por Zebra Datepicker?

Tags: jquery-datepicker

Funciona perfecto esta funcion pero si quisiera cambiar el plugin y en vez de utilizar datepicker usara Zebra Datepicker ( https://stefangabos.github.io/Zebra_Datepicker/ ) como deberia cambiarlo?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Perdon, soy nuevo, esta pregunta es en referencia a este artículo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/549262/datatables-filtro-por-fechas-no-funciona-corractamente/561487#561487

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.